# How to extract word after a substring in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string contains a set of values i have extract a word(space should ignore) after a substring
I tried splitting the string

```
text = text.split("Vehicle Number",1)[1]
```

text contains `Vehicle Number 4092 casuality 230 \n report based on 23/54/2 accidents 0192`

I have to store the values (Dictionary)

```
Vehicle Number : 4092,
report based on : 23/54/2,
accidents : 0192
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. A clean way given a static set of words but dynamic positions:

```
text = "Vehicle Number 4092 casuality 230 \n report based on 23/54/2 accidents 0192"
text = text.split()

dictionary = {
    'Vehicle Number': text[text.index('Vehicle') + 2],
    'Report Based On': text[text.index('report') + 3],
    'Accidents': text[text.index('accidents') + 1]
}
```

Comment: The string  value can change , i tried taking the text by index , but will be a failure when string value changes ,

Comment: The string indices may change, but does the number of whitespaces change? @Naveen

Comment: The string may change to like this Vehicle Number 4092 casuality 230 \n report based on 23/54/2 accidents 0192  Incident Type N/A Start Lifetime 601.9 KM
Date/Time 1/14/21Trigger Lifetime63302.7 KM
Operator Number N/A

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Though the current code would still work for this second example (since the initial whitespaces are the same), I'll edit it to be more safe under a new assumption that new positions can occur anywhere. @Naveen